# Ошибки "Undefined variable" и "Uninitialized string offset"

Tags: php

Есть код с ошибками, нужно его поправить. Кода всего на 1 страницу. Здесь его показать не могу, т.к. его покупал и поэтому тем самым нарушу авторские права.

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: nxt in

и

> PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 0 in

Также, возможно, Вы найдете и другие ошибки.

Comment: > пишем свою цену за 1 исправленную ошибку

Ошибка ошибке разница! ;)

Comment: <code>PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: nxt in</code> <br />
и <code>PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 0 in</code> Также, возможно, Вы найдете и другие ошибки.

Comment: @nick777, это не сайт по содействию наxождения фрилансера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полагаю достаточно вставить в начале скрипта

```
 $nxt = '';
```

Тем самым явно указать, что переменная существует, до её использования.

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка исчезла.))

Answer (score 1):

Нотис не еррор, ошибка не предупреждение. А вообще, советую обратиться к автору, ибо нефиг продавать код такого качества.